# No content in http.Request.Body when read using Golang

Tags: http, go, io, request

Note: All error handling code is omitted for simplicity. I handled them locally, and no errors were produced.

In Golang, I tried to use the code below to read from a `http.Request.Body` from a POST request:

```
func readBody(req *http.Request) string {
    bytes, _ := httputils.DumpRequestOut(req, true)
    return string(bytes)
}
```

It shows a non-zero Content-Length, but no content returned:

```
ContentLength=413 with Body length 0
```

. I tried with the code below, also no luck:

```
func readBody(req *http.Request) string {
    bytes, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(req.Body)
    return string(bytes)
}
```

It returns an empty string. After googling, I found a blog about this problem: [Golang: Read from an io.ReadWriter without losing its content](https://medium.com/@xoen/golang-read-from-an-io-readwriter-without-loosing-its-content-2c6911805361). I tried to follow the pattern, still no luck:

```
func readBody(req *http.Request) string {
    bodyBytes, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(req.Body)
    // Restore the io.ReadCloser to its original state
    req.Body = ioutil.NopCloser(bytes.NewBuffer(bodyBytes))
    // Use the content
    return string(bodyBytes)
}
```

Any suggestions? Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Check returned errors (those underscores `'_'` in your code which you _gracefully_ omit). And post what they are if you can't figure out based on that. Also post how you acquire the `http.Request` that you pass to the functions above (e.g. post the context that calls the `readBody()` function).

Comment: oh i forgot to say i put _ for all errors is just for simplicity. I handled them properly in my code and no errors are found.

Comment: Are you sure there actually _is_ a non-empty body? If yes: why are you sure?

Comment: i've added what i got in the question, it's something like `ContentLength=413 with Body length 0`. Is it the supposed content I should get in the body? And is it because it's a POST request so that the Body is supposed to hold no content?

Comment: So there is no body. Content-Length can be wrong. Lot's of request do not have a body.

Comment: @nevets `Content-Length` is just an HTTP request header and it's value can be set to anything.

Comment: "And is it because it's a POST request so that the Body is supposed to hold no content?"

That part confuses me. Why would a POST request body not be supposed to have content? Is this request one you're receiving as a server or one you're sending as a client?

Answer (score 0):

If the request does not include an appropriate "Content-Type" header you may see a 0 length body when you try to read it.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/13000234)

Comment: Not sure what you mean? The question is asking why a 0 length body is being read and I've supplied a possible reason.

Comment: While it might be true, your answer sounds as it's not 100% accurate due to question you have provided. Also, it looks somewhat incomplete. :)

Comment: Ok, I've taken out the question.

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because you call `httputils.DumpRequestOut(req, true)` after the http client has performed the request and the body is drained.

Make sure you do the following step in order:

1. `httputils.DumpRequestOut(req, true)`
2. `resp, err :=http.DefaultClient.Do(req)`
3. `httputil.DumpResponse(res, true)`